# Domain Administrator does not have permission to remove a folder

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, permissions

I am a Windows domain administrator, and on my Windows 7 machine I have a folder that is owned by another domain user. When I right click and attempt to delete, it tells me that I don't have permission.

I logged out as myself and logged in as the domain administrator's account, attempted to delete, and again I am told that I don't have permission.

I logged out and logged back in as myself, and installed the latest version of Cygwin. Then I went to the folder above the offending folder, and performed `rm -r offendingfolder`. It worked. The folder is gone.

I presume there's no magic behind Cygwin and it uses the Windows authentication mechanism, so I need to know: Why couldn't I do this under Windows itself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is this question downvoted? He asks why it works with Cygwin.

I don't know exactly. My guess is, Cygwin has a clever trick to grant a group full control/modify by taking ownership to a specific file/folder prior to removing it. But, again, that's speculation from my point of view, studying source code is not one of my daily routines.

It can be done through native Windows tools. For example, see [KB268019](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/268019) on taking ownership. It explicitly states:

> Taking ownership does not automatically grant you permission to access it. You have to explicitly give the administrator permission to the folders and files.

When you are owner, you can change permission entries. Which, in this case, boils down to assigning your account at least ['Modify'-permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742461.aspx) to remove the offending folder.

Comment: Absolutely workflow is , take ownership first through advanced security, then add permissions so you can delete or read or whatever else you need to do

Comment: I am a UNIX person, so bear with me. What is the purpose of having the ability to take ownership and then add permissions? I have just taken ownership of a file that is owned by my system's "Administrators" user. Why not just allow my user identity to manipulate the file in the first place? I'm confused; there's no security in denying me an ability that I could just work around once I know how...

Comment: BTW, cygwin does not take ownership prior to removing it. It has deeper Windows Fu than that, as seen in my comment #2 to Joel Coel's answer, I can actually perform actions- an `ls` command, run as my user credentials- that fails under Windows' `cmd.exe`, run as domain Administrator credentials.

Comment: The security level is the same as using sudo. No sudo, no super cow powers. Users are not able to take ownership of files by default. Unless they are in the local administrators group, or have full access to a file (because it includes the change acl permission).

Comment: ...And it's not Cygwin, either. I can fire up an instance of Chrome as myself and do: `file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/mschwager/` and I will see the folder's contents. But poor ol' Explorer gives me "Access is denied." Methinks this is not a feature but a bug...

Comment: Ah! Ah! Ah! There it is! Under the Permissions for Documents and Settings, "Everyone" has "Deny" for "List folder contents". I set it to allow, and could see! Then I set it back to Deny, and windows says, "Deny entries take precedence over allow entries. This means that if a user is a member of two groups...the user is denied that permission." YES!!!! Understandable! Logical! Reasonable! Explicable! FOUND!!!!!!!!!!!! Thanks for all your help. And to the downvoter(s): Pbpbpbpbpbb! Some of us are not native to these lands, we need help. That's not wrong.

Comment: This gets the "answered" checkmark because the key is taking ownership. As Daniel says, then you can modify permissions and whatnot.

Comment: Sorry, but only because you don't understand something it is not a bug. "Documents and Settings" is an NTFS Juntion Point or symbolic link (`ln -s`). Check the permissions. It has `Everyone:(DENY)(S,RD)` where S=Special,RD=ReadDirectory. In Windows, DENY permissions take precedence and that is why you get a File not Found error. But try to `echo "hi" > test.txt` and check C:\Users.

Comment: Having said that: The DENY permission is for special cases and should not be used in you everyday practise. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779601%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: It seems, Daniel, that we are in complete agreement at this point, on all counts. Windows has what appears to be very reasonable UAC logic; the key is in the understanding. Coming from UNIX, we bring a set of expectations to the party. But Windows' UAC is not based on UNIX', obviously, so one needs to put one's UNIX-y assumptions on the shelf.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that, as of Windows Vista, administrator rights are not assumed. You must start a process with elevated permissions in order to actually have full administrator privileges. Think of this as the Windows equivalent to `sudo`.

Normally this can be done by right-clicking on the program and selecting `Run as Administrator`. For Windows Explorer, the process is already running and it's too late. But what you can do is click the start menu and type `explorer.exe` into the search box. Then you will be to right-click on the explorer.exe icon and use the Run as Administrator feature, which should give you your full administrator permissions.

If you really really want to (and please don't), you could also go disable UAC. But don't do that.

Comment: Upvoting because this is most likely a UAC issue, but you're wrong on one thing: you can't use "Run as Administrator" on `explorer.exe`, because Windows will *not* launch another instance of it and will just open a new window in the currently running `explorer.exe` process. But you can do that with `cmd.exe` and delete the file from there.

Comment: Massimo is correct, this doesn't work but the cmd.exe trick does. However, I notice that in my C drive I have a "Documents and Settings" folder that I cannot access (though I am an Administrator of my domain). So I ran a cmd.exe as administrator, then was able to go to the directory. However, dir says 'File not found". Even stranger, if I go to Cygwin I can cd to it and perform an `ls`. Using a name returned by that command, I can go back to my cmd.exe window and cd into the folder, and then do a `dir` of the subfolder just fine. Windows UAC is confusing.

Comment: "Documents and Settings" is not a folder. Have a second look at it.

Comment: UAC is very easy once you understand it. And it's easy to understand it. Read this: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-is-user-account-control#1TC=windows-7

Comment: As of Windows Vista, `C:\Documents and Settings` is a junction (roughly equivalent to a Unix symbolic link) to `C:\Users`.

Comment: @Daniel Even when you understand it perfectly, UAC still is a total nuisance; sometimes (as in the `explorer.exe` case) even "Run as Administrator" is not enough to get things done, and you have to resort to awkward workarounds in order to bypass one of the most badly designed security features I've ever seen.